# Does "want to be" mean 'tending to be so' or 'having such inclination'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is from the episode "[How We’re Learning To Talk To Animals](https://omny.fm/shows/stuff-you-should-know-1/how-we-re-learning-to-talk-to-animals)" of the podcast *Stuffyoushouldknow* :

> Josh: We're gonna go forward to Klaus Zuberbühler
>
> Chuck: Great name.
>
> Josh:  who is Swiss as, uh, as people who name their families Zuberbühler are **want(?) to be**.

My sense is that "**want to be**" is meaning 'tending to be Swiss' in this context.

I wonder whether "want to be" is used to mean 'tending to be so' or 'having such inclination' in conversational or informal English.

Comment: @Rakib How about this? : as people who name their families Zuberbühler **or** want to be. I looked up "or" in Webster dictionary and its pronunciation phonetic alphabet is "Southern also  ˈär".

Comment: @Rakib Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know if this is exactly on topic, but surely those Swiss folks didn't 'name' their family Zuberbühler any more than mine 'named itself' Harvey? Is this some hastily scripted podcast thing?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Should I close this post?

Comment: @qna - not in my opinion - it's has 2 votes already.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I am sure that is the joke.

Comment: "wont to be" is a simple archaic phrase you can trivially look up.  The completely pointless guesses and "jokes" here have simply totally confused the OP and put OP on the completely wrong track.

Comment: TIL it's *are wont* not *are want* even thought that's how it's pronounced. Either way there's always an *are* before it, which is why the title didn't make sense and there's three different things those each say. - "is a simple archaic phrase you can trivially look up" - Yeah,  IF YOU KNOW HOW TO SPELL IT RIGHT and include *are*.

Comment: @Mazura There isn’t always an _are_ (or other forms of _be_) before it. _Wont_ is only used predicatively, but you can still have reduced relative clauses (“People wont to be lazy enjoy life more”), introductory adjectival phrases (“Wont to be argumentative, he often got into fights with his colleagues”), etc. It’s also a noun, of course, especially used in the phrase ‘as was [his/her/their/…] wont’.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The word they used was not *want*, but *wont*, which is nowadays not used all that much. As a noun it means habit or practice: *It was her wont to walk to school*. **To be wont to** do something means, as you had surmised, to tend to do it, or be in the habit of doing it.

Comment: And from native speakers I've heard this regularly pronounced as a homophone to each of "want" and "won't" depending on the speaker. I think it's a rare enough word that a lot of people aren't really sure which is the "traditionally correct" one.

Comment: And in this particular context, "people who name their families Zuberbühler are wont to be Swiss" is intended to be humorous, because of course people do not choose their names, nor their nationality.

Comment: Yes, @MichaelKay, it is being used ironically, which is to say, with the “are in the habit of” sense, rather than the “tend to” sense.

Comment: Worth noting that the word "wont" in this sense (not to be confused with the unrelated word "won't") is quite archaic. It is essentially never used outside this idiom, and maybe some related ones. The idiom itself is pretty archaic. It's good to be able to understand it, but it's rare and I wouldn't suggest using it. (I'm a native American English speaker from California, if this turns out to matter.)

Comment: As a matter of interest, are you a (Native American) English speaker or a native (American English) speaker?

Comment: @Muzer - anyone you're heard who doesn't know it's "wont", and who pronounces it incorrectly, is simply poorly educated. It's a commonplace to hear poorly-educated people mispronouncing words, incorrectly repeating phrases they have heard somewhere but don't understand, mangling idioms, and so on. This is a non-event. It's wont.

Comment: As @GlennWillen mentions, quite simply, this is fairly archaic - that should be mentioned in the otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: @Fattie [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wont) accepts both the "want" and "won't" pronunciations. It seems they're in variation where Muzer lives, but when I'm from (Ontario, Canada), it's strictly pronounced like "want".

Comment: @Fattie The historically oldest pronunciation (and also the prestige pronunciation traditionally taught in _education_) is /wʌnt/, rhyming with _hunt_. If you’re going to be prescriptive, that’s the ‘only correct’ one. But considering that it’s by far the _least_ common pronunciation now, that’s a losing battle. Both /wɒnt/ and /woʊnt/ have been in more or less equally frequent use across dialects over the past couple of centuries, and there is absolutely **nothing** to support either being any more ‘correct’ than the other, except within a specific dialect area.

Comment: As a British English speaker I've always heard it pronounced as rhyming with font rather than want or won't.